# Access unordered_map keys directly in std::set_interstection?

Tags: c++, unordered-map

I am passing a `unordered_map` to a function and accessing its keys to do `set_intersection` against a vector of strings. right now, to access the `unordered_map` keys i am iterating entire map and storing the keys in a separate vector that is `vec` and using the `vec` vector in `set_intersection`.

My question is

Instead of storing the keys in a separate vector can't i use the keys directly in the `set_intersection` ?

My sample code looks like this

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

void func(const std::unordered_map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>> dict) {
    std::vector<std::string> vec;
    std::vector<std::string> final;
    vector<string> stringVec = {"one", "two"};
    sort(stringVec.begin(), stringVec.end());

    
    
 // Here i am reserving the space for the dict and accessing its keys and storing in a vector. And using the vector in std::set_interstection.     
    vec.reserve(dict.size());
  for(const auto& x: dict) {
      vec.push_back(x.first);
  }
  sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());
  std::set_intersection(vec.begin(),vec.end(),stringVec.begin(),stringVec.end(),std::back_inserter(final));
  
  for (auto& y: final) {
      cout << y <<std::endl;
  }

}


int main()
{
 std::unordered_map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>> dict;
   dict["one"].push_back("alpha");
   dict["two"].push_back("beta");
   dict["three"].push_back("gamma");
   
   func(dict);

    return 0;
}
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: You have a bigger problem. `std::set_intersection` requires sorted input ranges. The vector you build isn't guaranteed to be sorted.

Comment: Your whole program boils down to checking whether the key `"two"` is present in the map. (or would, had it not exhibited undefined behavior by way of passing an unsorted range to `set_intersection`). Just do that directly with `dict.find("two")`, as in `if (dict.find("two") != dict.end()) std::cout << "two" << std::endl`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik thanks for responding. the above code snippet is just a sample. i am not just checking for only `two`,  i am checking for a set of strings consider  5 atleast.

Comment: @Unslander Monica thanks, i have updated my sample code snippet

Comment: `std::back_inserter` wont work even if you made a custom comparator.  You'll need to make you own version that coverts from the map's value type to the vector's value type.  The comparator could be done like [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e0799be62a8f0885)

Comment: Probably the easiest solution is just plain `for (auto& s: stringVec) { if (dict.find(s) != dict.end()) { doSomething(s); } }` . `set_intersection` is of no help here - `std::sort` alone is more expensive than this loop.